# waiting for the the function to finish before returning a promise

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, promise

```
someFunction() {
  if (array.length > 0) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      array.map(item => {
        AXIOS.postItem(item).catch(err => {reject('error')});
      });
      resolve('resolve');
    });
  }
}

mainFunction() {
  Promise.all([this.someFunction()]).then(() => {
    this.invokeTheRest();
  )}
}
```

In my case, the some function always returns `resolve`, even before the `AXIOS.postItem()` is executed or caught.

How could i wait for the `AXIOS.postItem()` to execute? And if there is error caught in `catch` how could i NOT proceed to `this.invokeTheRest()` ?

Comment: You have kind of put your `Promise.all` in the wrong place..  do something like ->  `return Promise.all(array.map(item......`  And then from mainFunction,  `this.someFunction().then(....`  And of course don't bother with `return new Promise`  Oh, and lastly, take out the `catch` in your `map`, or the error won't propagate.

Comment: a bit confused with why i have to put `array.map..` inside `Promise.all` and then also call `this.someFunction` @Keith

Answer (score 2):

Change the body of someFunction to just:

```
someFunction () {
    return array.map(item => AXIOS.postItem(item));
}
```

So that it returns an array of Promises that can be used with Promise.all .

Comment: then how to catch an error and stop executing further if `AXIOS` call fails?

Comment: @user7187525  Promises have no concept of cancellation,.  If you send an array of Promises to promise.all, they will all be executed in parallel, and either resolve if all promises were successful, or reject if one of them failed.

Comment: You can't with this or with your original code. This code initiates all the AXIOS calls at once so they can be done in parallel. If you want to stop further calls when one fails you can't do that, you have to wait for each one to succeed before starting the next one.

Comment: yeah, in this case `Promise.all([this.someFunction()])` returns a list of `undefined` all the time and keeps invoking the `this.invokeTheRest` even if some of the api calls failed before that

Comment: If really want to execute your calls in series. A nice way would be to await each AXIOS call inside a for loop and put the whole loop into a try..catch statement.

Comment: Did you accidentally put `{}` around `AXIOS.postItem(item)`? That would explain the `undefined`s. If you did you need to either add a `return` in front (inside the `{`) or remove them.

Comment: Also you should not have `[] `inside your call to `Promise.all`. Just `Promise.all(this.someFunction())`.

Comment: @user7187525 This will not run `invokeTheRest` unless all the AXIOS calls succeed. That's what `Promise.all` does.

Answer (score 1):

Having someFunction return an array of promises I would say is a coding anti-pattern.

The way I would go is to return the Promise.all from someFunction, this will then make someFunction into a Promise, that you can then use just like any other promise.

eg.

```
someFunction() {
  return Promise.all(
    array.map(item => AXIOS.postItem(item)));
}

mainFunction() {
  this.someFunction().then(() => {
    this.invokeTheRest();
  });
}
```